# Modify a scope variable from within a controller. After a call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Ok, so, lets start off with an apology, I sincerely apologize if this has been asked before and also if this question is very dumb.

I am pretty new to AngularJS and have recently been successful in getting past the CORS errors, the login via Parse, I even wrote an API for my app in NodeJS with Express.js and I have just hit a somewhat hard road block.

Basically,  I have some code and this is how it looks:

```
         $http.get('http://localhost:3000/users?id=' + CryptoJS.MD5(config.SERVER_KEY)).then(function(resp) {
           //console.log('Success', resp);
           $scope.post = resp.data;
         }, function(err) {
           console.error('ERR', err);
           $scope.post = err;
         })
```

My API router /users is actually misleading but this just gets a bunch of posts from my database and displays it. See if it is successful, it will save it in the $scope.post variable, but say for example I am "done" with a post and have seen the post. And after a button is clicked to "remove it" it is removed from the array. So here is how my code looks:

```
        $scope.next = function() {
          $scope.post.shift();
        }
```

Unforunately, it doesn't seem to work. And I have even tried " delete $scope.post[0] " both have failed.

I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong, it would be great if someone could help me and point me to my mistake or the right direction? Thank you very much!

EDIT, here is how my code for the HTML page looks:

```
<div class="item center">
  <h2>{{post[0].title}}</h2>
</div>

<div class="item item-body" align="center">
  <div ng-if="post[0].postType == 'image'">
    <img src="{{post[0].postBody}}" height="{{width}}" width="{{width}}" />
  </div>
  <div ng-if="post[0].postType == 'text'">
    <p>"{{post[0].postBody}}"</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
   <a class="tab-item" ng-onClick="next()">
    <i class="icon ion-arrow-right-c"></i>
     NEXT!
   </a>
   <a class="tab-item" href="#" ng-onClick="like({{post[0].id}})">
    <i class="icon ion-heart"></i>
     Like ({{post[0].likes}})
   </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

EDIT 2 Here is how the $scope.post looks:

```
[{"likes":1,"ownerId":"uVziWLz1uy","postBody":"This is the very, first, ever, post.","postType":"text","title":"Hello World","objectId":"Q2wnN9S3Kg","createdAt":"2015-05-10T19:48:46.216Z","updatedAt":"2015-06-20T16:37:21.800Z"},{"likes":55,"ownerId":"uVziWLz1uy","postBody":"http://images7.alphacoders.com/311/311587.jpg","postType":"image","title":"Nature","objectId":"lVFQIxUbyU","createdAt":"2015-06-20T17:25:39.752Z","updatedAt":"2015-06-20T17:26:40.590Z"}]
```

Comment: Have you tried $scope.post.splice(0, 1); (assuming you're sure it's the first item in the array)

Comment: Failed how? Did you do a console.log before and after the operation? Does nothing change? Or does the operation (of removing the item from the array) succeed but you don't see it in the view?

Comment: @laggingreflex I think it may actually be the operation that happens, but just doesn't update. Could you please show me how to do a console.log of the $scope.post? Like where should it be placed? Inside of the $scope.next? Because that isnt working for some reason.

Comment: @ajmajmajma Yes I have tried that as well, but looking into laggingreflex 's answer, that may be the problem, the reloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this would be a comment, but I don't have the rep to comment. I just tested your code and it works, ASSUMING that $scope.post is a valid array of objects or strings.

I assume there are other things in the response and data is the array? If not, that's your problem. Remove the ".data" part from resp.

```
$scope.post = resp.data;
```

Edit: lol, so the issue was in the html, from comments:

This line

```
<a class="tab-item" ng-onClick="next()">
```

should be

```
<a class="tab-item" ng-click="next()">
```

A reminder for us all that ng-click is an unintuitive transition from javascript's "onClick".

Comment: Data contains the main array, what do you mean that could be the problem? Could you please elaborate, thank you!

Comment: It was just a fail-safe question on whether or not resp.data is actually an array - looks like it is and you can safely ignore it. Anyway, one more thing to try would be to set $scope.post.data = resp.data; Don't ask me why, but sometimes angularjs will treat an object as immutable unless it's inside another object. I have only known it to be an issue with strings though. But give it a try just in case. Shouldn't take more than two minutes. If that doesn't work and nobody else has an answer, I recommend posting more of your code.

Comment: no unfortunately it is not working. I am going to keep trying, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: That sucks =/. Good luck. Just to cross-off one thing, I did test your $scope.next() function verbatim (since that takes 2 seconds also), and that works on any normal array, so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I am thinking it may be the update on the screen. Maybe it is just not showing the updates on screen. Linking back to laggingreflex's suggestion. I am updating my post with the data and how it looks.

Comment: Put in a loop inside the $scope.next function. Basically for (var i = 0; i <  $scope.post.length; i++){console.log("Post property: " + $scope.post[i].prop} and see if it took anything off. If it did, that will tell you it's a view problem. Alternatively, just console log $scope.post.length to see if took an element off. Angular is pretty sure good updating the view, so I would be absolutely sure it's removing the element first.

Comment: There are no updates in the google chrome console section or on the terminal. What could that mean? Sorry if I just seem like a complete idiot, I rather code this all in C++ than have to deal with AngularJS, never had so many problems before, but I am definitely missing some stuff somewhere. Also, I think I might have not mentioned this, I am using Ionic Framework.

Comment: Assuming your console outputs worked before, it means that the console.log statement isn't being hit. Make sure $scope.next is triggering overall. Unfortunately I can't comment on ionic. And yea, these problems where you don't know which part of the code is causing the problem are the worst.

Comment: FOUND IT!!!!!! This line <a class="tab-item" ng-onClick="next()"> should be <a class="tab-item" ng-click="next()">!!! You were going with the standard javascript onClick from habit =) Been there.

Comment: hahaha, oh man, I am so glad we found it. It's always little %^#$ like this that only comes out from talking about it. Have a good day man.

Comment: Yeah, oh boy, I didnt even think about it. I am so used to Javascript that I didnt even think that ionic framework might change it from onClick to click. Thanks for all your help! And you too, have an amazing day :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `$scope.post` is an array and i would assume if you might be looping through the this in your views with a next button in binding to current scope.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="p in post">
    {{ p }}
    <button ng-click="next( $index )">Next</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So now you can remove the element upon the next button click.

```
$scope.next = function( i ) {
  $scope.post.splice( i, 1 );
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but using the ng-repeat="p in post" just seems to show all of the posts on the page, I am going to update my answer now with the actual code for the page. Thank you!